# Can I make all of the roles defined in an <asp:RoleGroup> required? (i.e. user must meet all roles)

Tags: asp.net, security, roles, webforms

Let's say I have a rolegroup as follows:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lvDoSomeStuff" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="RoleOne,RoleTwo">
            <ContentTemplate>
            ...
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Is there a way I can make it so that a user must meet RoleOne **and** RoleTwo to satisfy the RoleGroup? By default, if a user is in either of the two roles, they will be granted access.

I know I can do this via the code-behind, but I'd prefer to be able to wrap some content template with this markup instead of having to wrap it in a panel and hide the panel programmatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of telling the RoleGroup section to require all roles. You must implement that type of logic in the code-behind.